# Select data where column value exists in seperate rows for same reference id

Tags: mysql, select

This is on a MySQL database. Locations have services.

What I want is to get all results where `service_id` is 2 `AND` 3, not `OR` so using `IN` is out I believe.

**Database**

```
----------------------------
| location_id | service_id |
----------------------------
|      1      |      2     |
|      1      |      3     |
|      2      |      2     |
----------------------------
```

**Expected Results**

```
----------------------------
| location_id | service_id |
----------------------------
|      1      |      2     |
|      1      |      3     |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your query:

```
SELECT
   T.location_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(T.service_id) AS serviceids
FROM `Table` AS T
GROUP BY T.location_id
HAVING serviceids IN ('2,3');
```

You could use `ORDER BY` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT 
   T.location_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(T.service_id ORDER BY service_id ASC) AS serviceids
FROM `Table` AS T
GROUP BY T.location_id
HAVING serviceids IN ('2,3');
```

**EDIT**, Another way:

```
SET @LOCATION_ID=0;
SET @LOCATION_ID=(
    SELECT
        T.location_id
    FROM `Table` AS T
    GROUP BY T.location_id
    HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(T.service_id ORDER BY T.service_id ASC) LIKE '%2,3%');
SELECT
    T.location_id,
    T.service_id
FROM `Table` AS T
WHERE T.service_id IN (2,3) AND T.location_id=@LOCATION_ID;
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: What if the ID's are not in order, do I just always do an order by T.service_id?

Comment: You can make this work better with one `Stored Procedure`.

Comment: I recommend increasing the group_concat_max_len at least for this session: "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kludgy way:

```
SELECT location_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(service_id) AS service_ids
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY location_id
    HAVING service_ids = '2,3';
```

Comment: What if the result of `GROUP_CONCAT()` comes out as `'3,2'`?